# Network interfaces, reseting, default

Tags: networking

I messed my `/etc/network/interfaces` up, at some point of configuration I accidentally encoded it, so the state is read-only.
From then my system wont start this:

```
Starting configure network device           [FAIL]
Starting configure network device           [FAIL]
Starting configure virtual network device   [FAIL]
```

I wanted to edit the file with `nano` and it said VimCrypt with a bunch of cryptic symbols.

So should i delete interfaces and set it up again?

Answer (score 2):

- Remove the broken file

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/network/interfaces
  ```
- Create a new one

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
  ```

  and add the lines below

  ```
  # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback
  ```
- Correct the permissions

  ```
  sudo chmod 644 /etc/network/interfaces
  ```